# Keep getting is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js and trying to export a function from another class but when I do I always
get the function is not a function. please help

file1.js

```
const fbiChannel=require('./fbiChannel.js');
fbiChannelVar= new fbiChannel();
fbiChannelVar.editFbiChannel();
```

fbiChannel.js

```
class fbiChannel {}

   module.export= function editFbiChannel() {
    //* some random code **
    return;
   };
```

Comment: you are not exporting the class so calling the function with `new` doesnt make sense

Comment: can you give any example of a code I should follow?

Comment: please read about exports in node.js , u should be able to understand. If you dont please feel free to tag me in comments, I will revert, but please give some time

Comment: The property module.exports is used to export an object from a module.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what goal you tried to achieve.  But technically to make it work without error you should do something like:

fbiChannel.js

```
class FbiChannel {

  // now it is a method of the class
  editFbiChannel() {
    //* some random code **
    return;
  }
}

// Export the class.  Better to start class name with CapitalLetter
module.export = FbiChannel;
```

And file1.js would be:

```
const FbiChannel = require('./fbiChannel.js');
fbiChannelVar = new FbiChannel();
fbiChannelVar.editFbiChannel();     // some random result :)
```

Again, that might be not your intention, but it is not clear from your question, what the intention is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to export the class.
You should be doing something like:

```
class FbiChannel {
    editFbiChannel() {
        //* some random code **
    }
}

module.exports = FbiChannel;
```

Then you can do the following in file1.js:

```
const FbiChannel = require('./fbiChannel.js');
const fbiChannel = new FbiChannel();
fbiChannel.editFbiChannel();
```

Answer (score -1):

there is the answer for everyone

file2.js

```
class file2 {
    constuctor() {

    }

    file2Function() {
    //line of code
    }
 }
```

file1.js

```
file2=require('file2.js');
file2Variable=new file2();
file2Variable.file2Function();
```

Comment: it is effectively just a copy of 2 answers already here.  it also misses module.exports, so it is not as precise as the other 2.